# Scala object extending Set instance

Tags: scala, scala-collections

We know in Scala one can initialize the instance of the superclass of a singleton `object` by calling a constructor after the `extends` keyword, like so:

```
class C(val v: Int)
object Obj extends C(1)
```

Now, collections in the standard library are implemented in quite a peculiar way, delegating their construction methods to companion objects. What if I wanted `Obj` to extend some instance of Set? At first I was naively tempted to write:

```
object Obj extends Set[Int](1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But the compiler complained, bringing my mind to the problem I'm posing here. Am I misconceaving some fundamental Scala hierarchy design rule?

**EDIT:** I am exposing my use case to clarify why I feel the need to subclass Set.

```
trait Group[A] extends Set[A] {
    def add(x: A, y: A): A
    val zero: A
    def inverse(x: A): A
}

class CyclicElement(v: Int) {
    val value = v % 4
    override def equals(x: CyclicElement) = value == x.value
}

object CyclicElement {
    def apply(v: Int) = new CyclicElement(v)
}

object CyclicGroup extends Set[CyclicElement](Zero, A, B, C) with Group[CyclicElement] {
    override def add(x: CyclicElement, y: CyclicElement) = CyclicElement(x.value + y.value)
    override val zero = CyclicElement(0)
    override def inverse(x: CyclicElement) = CyclicElement(4 - x.value)
}
```

Comment: 1) `immutable.Set` is a trait and thus doesn't have constructors. 2) General concrete immutable implementations `TreeSet` and `HashSet` have private constructors, and are also `deprecatedInheritance` with a comment `"The implementation details of <...> sets make inheriting from them unwise."`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains because an object is a singleton and, by definition of an object, cannot take parameters at construction. On the other hand, Set is an abstract interface, so one has to implement missing methods, whether you want to create an object or a class:

```
scala> class SI extends Set[Int]{}
<console>:10: error: class SI needs to be abstract, since:
it has 4 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from class SI, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  // Members declared in scala.collection.GenSetLike
  def iterator: Iterator[Int] = ???

  // Members declared in scala.collection.SetLike
  def -(elem: Int): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = ???
  def +(elem: Int): scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = ???
  def contains(elem: Int): Boolean = ???

       class SI extends Set[Int]{}
```

However, one can make an ugly workaround like this:

```
scala> object Obj extends Set[Int] {
     | val content = Set[Int](1,2,3,4)
     | def -(elem: Int) = content-elem
     | def +(elem: Int) = content+elem
     | def contains(elem: Int) = content.contains(elem)
     | def iterator: Iterator[Int] = content.iterator
     | }
defined object Obj

scala> Obj + 5
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

(or you can declare `content` to be a mutable Set to keep the changes)

UPDATE:

The solution is to derive your Object from one of the concrete implementation of the Set:

```
scala> object Obj extends scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int]
defined object Obj

scala> Obj += 5
res4: Obj.type = Set(5)
```

Comment: What is the point with an object taking parameters or being constructed? I don't think I see anything like this in the code I posted. Besides I am aware that one might solve with such a workaround, it just feels wrong. I am in fact asking for a more elegant way.

Comment: See update for the answer. Make your object extend HashSet, TreeSet or any other implementation that would be suitable for you.

Comment: Take immutable HashSet then. But you'll get the warning about an unsafe implementation.

Comment: But then using `+=` is not allowed!

Comment: Of course not, because you cannot change immutable collection.

Comment: You can't set elements of immutable set when extending, there is no constructor for that. Also, it's `deprecatedInheritance`, and thus will become `final` soon.

Comment: So is that, and I quote, ugly workaround is the only way?

Comment: BTW looking at your example in pastebin, I don't immediately see why your object has to be derived from the Set, it does not seem to use any of its properties there. May be you only need an implicit object with a set of helper methods?